# Elasticsearch entire document search (Smart Search)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to write a query to be able to search across all fields in my Elasticsearch index. I used the bulk API to insert data to es and didn't choose any particular analyzer while indexing. By default my fields will be analyzed and I don't want to change my indexing.

I want to create a query that searches a piece of text inside all fields in elasticsearch and returns all documents which contain that text as a substring in some field. One way is to use the MatchPhrasePrefix query for each field along with the OR boolquery across all fields to search all over the document. Some of my fields are strings and some are maps of strings. MatchPhrasePrefix query for string is fine. But for the maps of strings, the keys are not fixed and the user can enter any key and any number of keys. So I am stuck on how to use the MatchPhrasePrefix query across all keys of such a map, where keys themselves are not fixed. If the keys were fixed , I would have looped across the map entries and used the query MatchPhrasePefixQuery("mapname.key","string") along with OR query.

I agree I can use QueryString and SimpleQueryString and use wildcard on keys like Query("mapname.*","string"), but it's not giving me correct results. So I am using MatchPhrasePrefix query as my fields are analyzed.

Any suggestions on how I can search a string in such a dynamic map field. If not this, then how can I search a string across my document in elasticsearch 7.4 where there is no _all field?

Comment: Please go through my answer and let me know if you have further questions

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to read and its better if you break your question and provide necessary information to solve the issue.

If you just care about:

> Any suggestions on how I can search a string in such a dynamic map
>   field. If not this, then how can I search a string across my document
>   in elasticsearch 7.4 where there is no _all field?

Then, it can be easily achieved using [copy_to](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) functionality of elasticsearch which is available in your elasticsearch version ie 7.4. As mentioned in the doc

> The copy_to parameter allows you to copy the values of multiple fields
>   into a group field, which can then be queried as a single field. For
>   instance, the first_name and last_name fields can be copied to the
>   full_name field as follows:

Please note the entire example is shown in the link ie, Defining index, indexing sample docs, and search query.

Let me know if you face any issue and happy to help further.